# What does "stretch up" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

Here is the context:

> If you have to **stretch up** to get the belt’s prong in that last hole, you will be less able to exert pressure with your own abdominal musculature, since it must be contracted to actually generate force.

I cannot get whether the author means to stretch up the belt or the body. And I have never heard the phrasal verb *stretch up*. Does it mean the same as *stretch*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stretch can mean to straighten the body, arms, or legs, so that they are as long as possible. To stretch up means to straighten the body vertically. This will cause the admomenal muscles to contract, allowing the belt to be tightened. A person might also need to stretch up (or upwards) to reach a high place such as a shelf.

[Stretch](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stretch)